# Geolocation Leaflet Marker not removing old one

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet

I have some Leaflet geolocation code which every time it updates the geolocation I get a new marker but the old markers are not removed so I'm ending with lots of markers instead of one.

Here is the code:

```
function locate() {
  mymap.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});
}

function onLocationFound(e) {

    var radius = e.accuracy;

      L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + " >>").openPopup();

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(mymap);
}

mymap.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

// call locate every 3 seconds... forever
setInterval(locate, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no code to remove the marker, so it doesn't get removed.

Try this (adapted from https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/182084/120862):

```
var currentlocation, currentradius;

function locate() {
  mymap.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});
}

function onLocationFound(e) {

    var radius = e.accuracy;

    if (currentlocation)  { 
         mymap.removeLayer(currentlocation);
         mymap.removeLayer(currentradius);
    }


      currentlocation = L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + " >>").openPopup();

      currentradius = L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(mymap);
}

mymap.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

// call locate every 3 seconds... forever
setInterval(locate, 5000);
```